# Xuggle on android

Tags: java, android, hyperlink, crash, xuggle

Am trying to use the libraries form Xuggle in my android app.

I have added the all the jar files to my app. When i use the xuggle functions I do not get any warnings after importing required xuggle packages. But at run time my app crashes with the following error .

**"Caused by unsatisfied Link error : Library xugle-xuggler not found"**

Is this because android does not support xuggle or am I missing something while linking.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was looking into something similar. I believe you must first compile the sources for Xuggle with the NDK. And that's never fun.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added the library to your build path when building an APK.

Comment: yes I have, else it would thrown an error at compilation right ?